# SQL - Only want a Grouped by record if a field is only a specific value and does not exist as another value

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, relational-database

So Using this:

```
SELECT FacFirstName, FacLastName, FacDept, OffTerm
FROM Faculty, Offering
WHERE Faculty.FacSSN=Offering.facSSN
GROUP BY FacFirstName, FacLastName, FacDept, OffTerm
```

I am able to get this:

[image]

I want all people that have 'winter' in offTerm and nowhere else. So I want the 2nd row and the last row. I **do not** want Nicki (2nd last row) because she has a record with an offTerm of 'SPRING' aswell as 'WINTER'

My train of though has lead me to believe that maybe I need to count the occurrences of a table with winter only and compare them with a table that has everything but winter. If the record in winter table is 1 and record does not exist in the other table then get it. Im not sure how to do this.

Comment: I m using access. I removed MySql my bad

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT FacFirstName, FacLastName, FacDept
FROM Faculty
INNER JOIN Offering
  ON Faculty.FacSSN = Offering.facSSN
GROUP BY FacFirstName, FacLastName, FacDept
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN OffTerm <> 'WINTER' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

If `OffTerm` is not nullable, then the above query will return the required results. Otherwise you should add the folloing to the `HAVING` clause of the query:

```
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN OffTerm = 'WINTER' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

**Note:** You should consider switching to usage of modern, *explicit* join syntax, as in the query above.

Comment: I'm using access so Im pretty sure my syntax for what you did is this
    HAVING COUNT(switch( OffTerm <> 'WINTER' , 1 , true , 0)) = 0
This returned no records

Comment: @user2436807 I don't understand, did the query I suggest work, or not?

Comment: No it didn't solve my problem. It ran but returned an empty table

Comment: @user2436807 It should work as the query uses standard ANSI SQL syntax. Can you post some sample data for `Faculty` and `Offering` tables?

Comment: Faculty: https://i.gyazo.com/32ce175207f7c3d602eab25bd8f907a8.png Offering: https://i.gyazo.com/793125035a03a411e81726bf86cf1d63.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select * from (select FacFirstName,FacSSN,count (OffTerm)  from (
SELECT FacFirstName, FacLastName,Faculty.FacSSN,FacDept, OffTerm
FROM Faculty, Offering
WHERE Faculty.FacSSN=Offering.facSSN
) AS T GROUP BY FacFirstName, FacSSN having count=1) AS K join Offering AS O on K.FacSSN=O.FacSSN where O.OffTerm='WINTER'
```

Comment: select * from (select FacFirstName,FacSSN,count(OffTerm) from (
SELECT FacFirstName, FacLastName,Faculty.FacSSN,FacDept, OffTerm
FROM Faculty, Offering
WHERE Faculty.FacSSN=Offering.facSSN
) AS T GROUP BY FacFirstName, FacSSN having count(offTerm)=1) AS K INNER JOIN Offering AS O on K.FacSSN=O.FacSSN where O.OffTerm='WINTER'

Comment: I made these changes to get it to run: count(offTerm) = 1, and K INNER JOIN OFFERING. It wouldnt run without these changes. This didnt give me the desired result.

Comment: Hi user2436807, Could you tell me what output this query gave ?? As per me it should give second and second last record.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
SELECT table1.FacLastName, table1.FacFirstName, table1.FacDept
FROM (

SELECT FacFirstName, FacLastName, FacDept, Count(OffTerm) AS termCount
FROM Faculty, Offering
WHERE Faculty.FacSSN=Offering.facSSN
GROUP BY FacFirstName, FacLastName, FacDept

) AS table1 INNER JOIN (

SELECT FacFirstName, FacLastName, FacDept, Count(OffTerm) AS termCount
FROM Faculty, Offering
WHERE Faculty.FacSSN=Offering.facSSN
GROUP BY FacFirstName, FacLastName, FacDept, Offterm
HAVING offTerm = 'WINTER'

) as table2
ON table1.FacFirstName = table2.facFirstName AND
table1.FacLastName = table2.facLastName AND
table1.FacDept = table2.FacDept AND
table1.termCount = table2.termcount
```